# ruby watir - get all divs inner contents from search

Tags: ruby, watir

I am attempting to scrape a website (respectfully). I tried with Nokogiri, then mechanize, then because the website i am scraping is loading a form dynamically, I was forced to use a webdriver. I am currently using ruby's watir.

What i am trying to do, is to fill out the dynamic form with a `select`, clicking submit, going to the results part of the page (form renders result on same page), and collecting all the divs with the information (traversing through sub-divs looking for hrefs).

```
 def scrape
    browser = Watir::Browser.new

    browser.goto 'http://www.website-link.com'

    browser.select_list(:id => 'city').select('cityName')

    browser.link(:id, 'btnSearch').click

    # this part; results from search are in this div w/ this ID
    # however, iterating through this list does not work the way i expected
    browser.div(:id, 'resultsDiv').divs.each do |div|
      p div
    end

    browser.close
  end
```

right now this returns

```
#<Watir::Div: located: true; {:id=>"resultsDiv", :tag_name=>"div"} --> {:tag_name=>"div", :index=>0}>
#<Watir::Div: located: true; {:id=>"resultsDiv", :tag_name=>"div"} --> {:tag_name=>"div", :index=>1}>
#<Watir::Div: located: true; {:id=>"resultsDiv", :tag_name=>"div"} --> {:tag_name=>"div", :index=>2}>
```

which looking at the page source looks like there are 3 divs inside of the `resultsDiv` which is probably what those indexes are. I guess what i was *expecting* (coming from Nokogiri/Mechanize) is an object to manipulate.

does anyone have any experience doing this that could point me to the right direction?

Comment: Those are objects. The index is assigned to the selector instance variable for elements created from collections so they be relocated if they go stale. `p div.text ` or `p div.inner_html` what you are looking for? Also, I just wrote watigiri gem that combines wait with nokogiri that I'd love feedback on if you want to try it out. https://github.com/titusfortner/watigiri

Comment: @titusfortner well the `resultsDiv` is a parent div that holds the information i am looking for, but getting to it would require some more traversing. what i was mainly looking for, is if these objects had access to their children elements.

Comment: If you could edit your question to include some sample HTML from the output of the search, and indicate what information you are trying to get, it would greatly help those trying to assist you.

Answer (score 0):

If you known the order that you want, you can do:
browser.driver.find_elements(:id => 'resultsDiv')[n].click
or
browser.div(:id => 'resultsDiv')[n].click
or
browser.div(:id, 'resultsDiv').div(:id,'id_n').click

Comment: Why using div() in the place of element() when you use Id? If it's id, it doesn't form the selenium equivalent with xpath, it just uses the id locator with selenium code. So using div() is useless in this place.

Comment: you can use id with any element, the divs can have the same id, you can use element or div, it's your choice, that's why I put differents ways to do the same.

Comment: I know id can be used with either element or div. But using div doesn't do any favor over element. But when you use div(text: 'something') over element(text: 'something') will do the favor. It frames the different xpath to the selenium driver.find_element().